# Why is my image displayed cropped from the top and bottom on my web page? (like it is zoomed in)

Tags: html, css, image, web-development-server

I am a complete beginner in CSS and JavaScript. I have added an image to my web page using HTML and CSS, but the upper half of the image is not visible. When I minimize the screen, the image shows up correctly. I have tried adjusting the CSS properties, but the issue persists. [This is how my website looks (The image on the left of 'Om Kakkad')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYJWb.png)

**here is my html code-**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mainPage.css">
        <script src="mainMenu.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
          
          <div class="container">
            <img src="om.jpeg" alt="My Image"/>
            <div class="text">
              <h1>Om Kakkad</h1>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. At, ex! Nam omnis ipsum ab repellat et impedit nulla tempore mollitia labore! Harum reprehenderit vitae excepturi, corporis fugit voluptatum perspiciatis quis!</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        
          <div class="card">
            <a href="your-page.html">
              <img src="#" alt="Your Image">
              <div class="text">
                <h2>Project 1</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque consequatur ad obcaecati deleniti enim earum cum quod, ullam rem, asperiores et soluta minima distinctio hic error assumenda ratione magnam repellat.</p>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          
          <div class="card">
            <a href="your-page.html">
              <img src="#" alt="Your Image">
              <div class="text">
                <h2>Project 1</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque consequatur ad obcaecati deleniti enim earum cum quod, ullam rem, asperiores et soluta minima distinctio hic error assumenda ratione magnam repellat.</p>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS Code -**

```
nav {
    background-color: rgb(184, 184, 184);
    padding: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    
  }
  
  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  li {
    margin: 0 10px;
  }
  
  a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: color 0.2s ease-out;
  }
  
  a:hover {
    color: #ccc;
  }

  main {
    padding-top: 60px; /* Set padding to make room for the fixed menu */
  }

body {
  background-color: #222;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
  
  .container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 50px;
    height: 500px;
  }

  img {
    size: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  }
  
  .text {
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
  
  h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  
  p {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.5;
  }
  
  .card {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    margin: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: calc(50% - 40px); /* Adjust width based on number of cards */
    transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
    float: left; /* Add float property to align cards side by side */
  }
  
  .card:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);
  }
  
  img {
    height: 200px;
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .text {
    padding: 20px;
  }
  
  h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  
  p {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  
  a {
    color: #222;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  a:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
  }
```

**Javascript Code -**

```
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card a');

cards.forEach(card => {
  card.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = card.getAttribute('href');
  });
});
```

**What I tried**: I have used the max-width property to adjust the size of the image and the margin-right property to add space between the image and text. I also tried adjusting the margin property for the container and the align-items property for the flex display.

**Expected Result**: I expect the entire image to be displayed on the web page without any cropping or cutoff.

Comment: Read up about object-fit cover. It is designed to fill the whole element - zooming in and cropping as you have described if it has to. It looks as though the aspect ratio of your image and the element are rather different and that you are seeing only the middle bit. object-fit: contain would ensure the whole image is shown (but of course there will be blank spaces either side of it on the viewport you have shown).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code you have a style

```
img {
    height: 200px;
    object-fit: cover; <--- that one
    width: 100%;
  }
```

that is the reason, the image is trying to fit into a container, basically, all your images will try to do that since you have this style for img tag

see documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

you can change it to `object-fit: contain;`

Answer (score 1):

Remove this style:

```
  img {
    height: 200px;
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

If you want to style a specific image to be `height: 200px`, add a `class="className"` to the image tag, and create a new style definition like this:

`<img src="image/source.jpg" class="className" />`

```
    .className {
        height: 200px;
    }
```